# Apache streaming timeout

Tags: apache, timeout, streaming

I have a web server with Apache 2.4 VC11 (http://www.apachelounge.com/download/) running on Win 7.

On my server I have some mp3's. I can queue them up in Winamp and the 1st one will begin streaming. However, after it plays for about 20-30 minutes it stops streaming, almost as if some time limit has been reached. I can reselect the song and drag the position to where it stopped playing and it will continue to play for about 20-30 minutes and stop again.

Is there a setting in the apache configuration I need to add/change to increase this limit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The files are anywhere from 50 to 120 minutes.

I set EnableSendfile to On in httpd.conf and that appears to have fixed it.